# Vertical align the child elements with different height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a vertically aligned child elements which have different heights.

Following is what I want to implement. Currently I set a different negative top margin on both buttons. I feel this can be done in a more cleaner way with a single generic ruling. Please share your thoughts.

[image]

---

Following is the code to illustrate the problem:

```css
.container {
  padding: 35px 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.action-button {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;

}

.small-screen {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<div class="container">

  <span class="title">
    Card header
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">

  <span class="title small-screen">
    Card header title here is longer
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanno_s88/2he35fnx/16/)

Comment: Do u want the text and button to be align vertically center?

Comment: yes that's right @Manikandan2811

Comment: @Pratiksha Kale - answer correct plz check that..

Comment: You have a better solution in this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b4mcgj1s/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `.container` style  with.

```
height: 120px;
display: flex;
border: 1px solid gray;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Check the snippet

```css
.container {
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.action-button {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.small-screen {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <span class="title">
        Card header
      </span>

  <button class="action-button">
        Action
      </button>

</div>

<br />

<div class="container">

  <span class="title small-screen">
        Card header title here is longer
      </span>

  <button class="action-button">
        Action
      </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the super fast response. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had display flex but not the other related CSS. Need to look into the flex thing. have a nice day!

Comment: I need to wait for 8 minutes so as to accept. :)

Comment: ooh, so my reply was quick :)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your .container class code to below code

```
   .container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Pratiksha, this was helpful, please keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

You could use absolute positioning instead of floating.

Add the line `position: relative` to your `.container` class to make sure that the buttons are positioned within this element.

Then remove the `float` from the `.action-button` class and instead add:

```css
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 50%;
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Here is the full working code snippet:

```css
.container {
  padding: 35px 2px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.action-button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);

}

.small-screen {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <span class="title">
    Card header
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">

  <span class="title small-screen">
    Card header title here is longer
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to solve the problem

Comment: @Raul It's from the article [How To Center Elements Vertically](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp) on w3schools

Answer (score 0):

> Use `display:table` along with `table-cell` with `vertical` align
>   `middle` property

```css
.container {
    padding: 35px 2px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.title {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.action-button {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.small-screen {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<div class="container">

  <span class="title">
    Card header
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">

  <span class="title small-screen">
    Card header title here is longer
  </span>

  <button class="action-button">
    Action
  </button>

</div>
```